# Derivative of $e^{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, derivatives

I'm trying to solve $\frac{d}{dx}e^{x}$: I know $\ln(e^{x})=x$, so $$(A)\frac{d}{dx}\ln(e^{x})=\frac{d}{dx}x=1$$I can also apply the chain rule : $$(B)\frac{d}{dx}\ln(e^{x})=\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x)\frac{d}{dx}e^{x}=\frac{1}{x}\frac{d}{dx}e^{x}\space(assuming\space x>0)$$
Combining $(A)$ and $(B)$ I got
$$\frac{d}{dx}e^{x}=x$$
What's wrong with this?

Comment: (B) should be $\frac{d}{de^x}\ln(e^x)\cdot \frac{d}{dx}e^x.$

Comment: We have $(\ln u)'=u'/u$, therefore $$\frac{d}{dx}\ln(e^x)=\frac{de^x}{dx}\frac{1}{e^x}$$

Comment: Use `$\ln$` for the output $\ln$. `\` stands in front of every operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an error in B. It should be:

$$\frac{d}{dx} \ln e^x = \frac{1}{e^x} \frac{d}{dx}e^x$$

Because  $\frac{d}{dx}\ln f(x) = \frac{1}{f(x)}\frac{d}{dx} f(x)$,

Answer (score 1):

You applied chain rule wrongly.

$\frac{d} {dx} f(g(x)) = f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x) $

In this case, that would give you:

$\frac d{dx} \ln e^x = \frac 1{e^x}\cdot \frac d{dx} e^x =1$

From which the required result immediately follows.